# sed - Piping a string before the last line in a file

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, sed

I have a command that prints a single line. 
I want to add/pipe this line to a file, just above its last line.

```
my_cmd | sed -i '$i' test
```

I just find an empty line in the correct place, above the last line. 
I notice that when I add any string as `'$i foo'`, the "foo" gets printed in the correct place, but I want the piped line to be printed.

How can I use STDIN instead of "foo"?

Comment: sample input and expected output would be better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
 sed -i "\$i $(cmd)" file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
1
2
3
4
5

kent$  sed -i "\$i $(date)" f

kent$  cat f
1
2
3
4
Tue Sep 30 14:10:02 CEST 2014
5
```

Comment: Thanks Kent, your solution basically works, but if the cmd generates white spaces (or tabs), they do not show. Please retry your command with $(date|sed 's/^/\t/'). Now all indentations are lost!

Comment: @TarekEldeeb now? `sed -i "\$i \ $(date|sed 's/^/\t/')" f`

Comment: try maybe `sed -i "\$i \\\n$( cmd | sed 's/$/\\/' )" file` (cannot test, no GNU sed available)

Comment: @Kent Perfect, but I do not understand how your last edit made sed consider leading white spaces??

Comment: @NeronLeVelu this only adds a proceeding "n". I replaced it by a "t", same result.

Comment: @Kent, your solutions adds an extra space. This one works perfect: `sed -i "\$i\\$(date|sed 's/^/\t/')" file`

Comment: @TarekEldeeb oh, yes, yours is correct, the `\` is for keeping the whitespaces in output.  for detailed info, `info sed` then search `a\'`

Answer (score 10):

Instead of passing your output to `sed` via pipe, you can use command substitution instead:

```
$ cat f
First line
Second line
Third line

$ sed -i '$i'"$(echo 'Hello World')" f
$ cat f
First line
Second line
Hello World
Third line
```

So in your case you can use:

```
sed -i '$i'"$(my_cmd)" test
```

Comment: Can you please explain how `sed -i '$i foo' file` adds foo before the last line. Basically i dont understand what `$i` means.

Comment: `$` means the last line, and `i` is a command that means "insert the following text before the preceding line number".

Answer (score 3):

The other answers should work too.

Here is another approach, which uses a syntax similar to your code snippet and is free from shell injection exploits.

```
$ seq 1 5 > test.input
$ echo hello/world | sed '${x;s/.*/cat/e;p;x}' test.input
1
2
3
4
hello/world
5
```

PRO: This solution is protected from [shell injection exploits](http://xkcd.com/327/).

CON: This is a GNU sed specific answer. So it may not be portable.

Comment: Replace `echo hello/world` by `your_cmd`. All indentations & special characters should be retained.

Comment: This seems to answer my exact question, but unfortunately I'm on cygwin! My sed complains as: sed: bad option in substitution expression

Comment: the `sed` on my cygwin box is also GNU sed & this solution worked for me on cygwin too. cygwin too old?

Comment: I use MobaXterm, I though it includes a full cygwin environment, but turned to be not. It has a minimalist sed, that's found in BusyBox  v1.19.2 (2012-06-12 22:17:17    ) multi-call binary.

Comment: aah! busybox! that's indeed minimal!

Comment: If you get busybox and checked its sed source code, you will find the following on line 3:: sed.c - very minimalist version of sed. Have a good day!