# Bash add entry to map

Tags: bash, sed

I have a (Nginx) config file like

```
types {
    text/html      html htm shtml;
    text/css       css;
    text/xml       xml;
}
```

In which I'd like to append an entry (wherever in the file) such as for example

```
types {
    text/html      html htm shtml;
    text/css       css;
    text/xml       xml;
    image/gif      gif;
}
```

I tried using sed as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26120524/3794110)

```
sed -i "\$i hello" mimes.types
sed: 1: "mimes.types": invalid command code m
```

I'm testing on MacOS with fish, but got the same error on bash.

Which command could I use here? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do an in-place edit, inserting a line with `hello` immediately before any line that consists of a `}` and optional whitespace:

```
perl -p -i -l -e 'print "hello" if /^\s*}\s*$/' mimes.types
```

Limitation with the above: if there are multiple `}` lines then you will get multiple `hello` lines.

The following will only print hello the once, even if there are multiple `}` lines:

```
perl -p -i -l -e 'print("hello"), $done=1 if /^\s*}\s*$/ && !$done' mimes.types
```

Explanation:

- `-p` loop over input, print every input line after executing the perl code
- `-i` edit the file in place (remove this to write to standard output instead)
- `-l` strips newline characters from input and appends them to output
- `-e 'print "hello" if /^\s*}\s*$/'` executes the `print` if the default variable (`$_`), which contains the line that was read in, matches the regular expression

In the second example, the variable `$done` is not explicitly initialised, but the `!$done` test works with an `undef` value the same as it would with an explicit `0`.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly, but uses `perl`. Will check if I can use perl in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error stems from a small difference between GNU `sed` (used on most Linux systems) and BSD `sed` (used on MacOS). The latter expects a [mandatory argument to `-i`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5694228/6770384). Try the following

```
sed -i .bak "\$i hello" mimes.types
```